# Why doesn't my connection to neo4j work (through Javascript)

Tags: javascript, neo4j, localhost

I am trying to make a interaction with my local neo4j dataset through javascript. But I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (13:20:43:754 | error, javascript)
>     at http://localhost:7474/?callback=jQuery111107695061936974525_1417522841327&{%22statements%22:[{%22statement%22:%22MATCH%20(n)%20RETURN%20count(n)%22}]}&_=1417522841328:2
>   success (13:20:43:958)
>     at public_html/index.html:34

I.e. I want to sent and receive queries with a web application.
This is my code by now:

```
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">   

var body = JSON.stringify({
            statements: [{
                statement: 'MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)'
            }]
        });
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:7474",
        type: "POST",
        data: body,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/jsonp"
    })
        .done(function(result){
            console.log(result);

        })
        .fail(function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });  </script>    

</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you're POSTing to the wrong endpoint.  Note your URL

[Here are the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request).

It should probably be this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
        type: "POST",
        data: body,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/jsonp"
    })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The error message is gone now, and in the console I get: [object Object] (14:01:26:806)
  at public_html/index.html:32. How can I get the results of the query printed?

Comment: First, you should accept this answer since it covers your question.  On printing the results, check the documentation I linked.  The result is a JSON object that has the format described by that documentation.  You need to inspect the JSON object in your "done" function.  Right now, you just do console.log(result).  Instead, look into the contents of the result object and print whatever you like.

Comment: Please bear with me as I am a beginner, but what I meant is how can I print the results of the query that I provided (thus all the records of my database).

Comment: This is a separate question about how to do JSON in javascript.  See this tutorial, and make sure to read the "example response" in the documentation I linked.  That's what the server will be sending back.   http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: Also google around for how to print out json - this question has been answered in many other places.

Comment: The documentation is a bit complicated for me to understand cuz I dont really know what part of the code is the receiving end of the interaction. Can you please provide and explain me the code for my situation , that would make my day!

Comment: The javascript you wrote above is the receiving entity.  What that JS does is to send a request to the server (at the endpoint I specified).  The response that comes back goes straight to the browser that's interpreting the javascript.  The browser runs the JS.  Before you work with neo4j, I would recommend going and reading the jquery tutorial for more basic concepts, since it looks like your code uses jquery.

Comment: On top of the that, you should be careful with queries like this in Javascript. Neo4j does not yet have authorization built into the database. The user's browser should never communicate directly with the server.